# 思い過ごせばいい - Actual meaning?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances, song-lyrics

In the first opening of One Piece titled "We are", there's a section that goes 「個人的な嵐は誰かのバイオリズム乗っかって思い過ごせばいい！」. Upon some googling, I found [following explanation](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1373244218):

> 個人的な悩みは誰かの生きていく上で繰り返す感情の変化、寝る起きるなどの生活リズムを見習って、忘れてしまえばいいという意味

which seems to make sense and is how I would have interpreted it initially. Though upon looking up the word 思い過ごす itself, I found [this entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84%E9%81%8E%E3%81%94%E3%81%99/) in the goo dictionary:

> 余計なことまで考える。あれこれと考えすぎる。「つい、いらぬことまで―・す」

「過ごす」itself also has following meaning in its own entry:

> （動詞の連用形に付いて）
>       ㋐適当な程度を越して事をする。「遊び―・す」「寝―・す」
>       ㋑そのままにしておく。「見―・す」「やり―・す」

Is 「思い過ごす」in this case supposed to have the meaning of "to stop thinking about it"? I can't see "to overthink one's own issues with the help of sb else" making much sense here (if we were to go with the original meaning of 「思い過ごす」).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

These lines are indeed hard to interpret, but after reading the [whole lyrics](https://www.uta-net.com/movie/78767/), my conclusion is that the interpretation in Chiebukuro is not correct, and your interpretation is not spot-on, either.

個人的な嵐は誰かのバイオリズム (lit. "Personal storms are someone's biorhythm") seems to imply you cannot perfectly control your situation and there are always stormy (or unlucky) days as well as good days. バイオリズム refers to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biorhythm), and it was a well-known concept at least in the 90's in Japan.

乗っかって思い過ごせばいい (lit. "You just have to ride it and 'think-over' it") thus seems to mean something like "You can just give it (=the storm) short shrift and forget it". It's true that 思い過ごす usually means "to overthink", but here I think it means "to (think and) forget it". For comparison, [やり過ごす](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%81%A3%E3%82%8A%E9%81%8E%E3%81%94%E3%81%99/#jn-223381) also has two meanings, "to overdo" and "to let it go", and the latter is more common.